# How can I deconstruct an js array with a wild card and pass eslint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want to write [Haskell wild card](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html#deftypes.wildcard) like syntax:

```
let [_, a] = [1, 2];
```

because I only want to use `a`.

But `eslint` warns that I declared `_`, never used.

Comment: isn't that declaring it as 1? your linter is probably just not hip to ES6 yet...

Comment: i believe `let [,a] = [1, 2];` will work

Comment: @LiYinKong Thanks for your hint. But I think Felix's answer is more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [this rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) to ignore variables matching a specific pattern:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": [2, {"varsIgnorePattern": "^_$"}]
    }
}
```

Comment: why would `a` be declared but not `_` in OP's code?

Comment: @dandavis: Not sure what you mean?